# ground water in old coal store

Tags: repair, water, basement

Hi my old coal store in cellar leaks ground water when it rains. Rest of my cellar is a converted kitchen and bathroom. House is over 100 years old. I have damp proofed with liquid rubber, tanking tar and epdm. Still leaking. Its not major water but causes a puddle and walls and ceilings have droplets of water. Its also freezing. The store is tall enough to stand in more like a small room with a door. Outside above the store is concreted to front of house. If i block the room up with a wall will water just seep through bricks over winter months or is this the best option? Thanks

Comment: You can't fix this from the inside, you need to divert the water away from the outside.

Comment: Can you clarify what a "coal store" is?  A freestanding container of some sort? What material is it made of? If the ceilings and walls of the **basement** have moisture, then that's condensation due to cold, and only a dehumidifier will help.  Does water only get in when there's rain -- i.e. thru a leak in the exterior part of the store?